# Why do my script paths get changed for my script app when I access it through the Finder's Script Menu?

Tags: applescript

Why do my script paths get changed for my script app when I access it through the Finder's Script Menu **and** BBEdit is the frontmost application?

FWIW, the change happens because I access an external script .scptd file within my main script.

One other item, the actual app in the global Finder Script Menu is an alias.

If I run my script within Script Editor, no change in paths - regardless of BBEdit.

If I run my script app alias by double clicking on it in any folder, even the global Finder's Script Folder, no change in paths regardless of BBEdit.

If BBEdit is in the background, no change in paths.

Only when BBEdit is frontmost and I click on the Finder's Script Menu and select my app, then the script app produces an error that says the following about my external .scptd file:

```
Macintosh HD:Users:johnlove:Library:my_Project:Project_Support:Scripts:External_Script_Libraries:externalLibrary.scptd
```

... and I definitely did not place the original or any of these folders/sub-folders in my Library folder.

???

Comment: **Finder** does not have a **Script Menu**, so what are you actually referring to? Are you by chance talking about the **Script Menu** that shows on the _menu bar_ if in **Script Editor** you have the **Script Menu: [√] Show Script menu in menu bar** checked, under **General** in its **Preferences**? Which is actually located at `/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Script Menu.menu` and is not a part of **Finder**. Also, you should probably post some _code_ so we can see if we can replicate your issue.

Comment: Script Menu on menubar when Finder is frontmost or any app for that matter. I *think* my problem centers on my use of AS’s key word me as in path to me. And so the path to my external script is relative to path to me.  But that doesn’t make sense because what I have in the menubar’s drop down menu is an alias. Anyway

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please edit in some of the pertinent code from your script app?

Comment: I will. But first I’m going to take the night off. Just came back from Arlington National Cemetery.

Comment: Back at it now. Once I put an **alias** of my Script App in the johnlove:Library:Scripts:Applications:Finder folder everything worked. If I put the **original** of my Script App there, then it messes up solely because I start all my paths with **set pathToThisScript to (path to me as text)** and build from there.

Comment: I would love to figure out the **magic** required to make my paths work no matter where the script is placed